# Output dynamic typo3 menu on 3rd party site

Tags: xml, json, typo3

I want to be able to show a typo3 menu on a third party site as there is a part of the site that is hosted on another system.  I would presume that the best way to do this would be through a json or xml feed but I can't see how to output json through typoscript or any other method dynamically in typo3?

Comment: I would go for the StephenKing's solution, included in the page in an iframe (simple) or loaded by JavaScript and inserted into the given spot on the page. Sure, you can load the menu content as json (would require a plugin or at least a custom PHP method to output it in TYPO3) or XML (can be done with TypoScript only), parse it and output it into the page but that's just extra work with no apparent benefit (unless the 3rd party site needs to have control over the output of the menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can grab the HTML via an http request, parse the HTML-document and insert the menu at the right place.

```
 $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page/with/menu/');
 ... crop
```

So in your TYPO3 webpage you need only to create a page which has the menu, you need on the other server. The parse the content and use only the menu. F.e. you can append and prepend an Marker to your menu.

```
 lib.menu = HMENU
 lib.menu {
   ... your config ...
   stdWrap {
     prepend = TEXT
     prepend.value = ####SomeMarkerBegin###
     append = TEXT
     append.value = ###SomeMarkerEnd###
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I inplemented something with file_get_contents

Answer (score 2):

You can even add a custom PAGE object (via TypoScript) with a different typeNum. Add to this PAGE object only the menu, not the contents (e.g. css_styled_content). You can disalbe all header code, too. The result is just the HTML code of the menu, which can be outputted directly on the other site.

Comment: Yep. It's possible to send this HTML code of the menu or directly with ajax, or through iframe, or through php request, which could be cached on the server side.

Comment: Through ajax.php isn't so easy, as you have to instantiate TSFE rendering on your own. Using another PAGE object makes it IMHO easier. And, of course, the menu should be cached in the other application ;)

Comment: Thanks @StephenKing I actually tried this, as it is a different domain I don't believe I can use ajax load?  I tried Iframing and it works well in IE but all other browsers you can't click on any of the other content that is under the iframe as event though the frame is transparent it is still layered above the content which prevents the click.  Is there another way around this?